# Nemo - How can I reload desktop from command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, linux-mint, cinnamon, nemo

I would like to know which command I can use in order to reload Nemo file manager from my terminal. I want to get exactly the same behavior as if I press the F5 key on the desktop.

Does someone knows how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by closing nemo & restarting it.

```bsh
nemo -q # Stop nemo
nemo --no-default-window &> /dev/null & # Start nemo without opening a new window and send output to /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

[`xdotool`](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/xdotool) is a great litte program for doing gui tasks from the command line.

You could do something like this:

> xdotool search --class nemo windowactivate %@ key F5

It will search for windows with the class nemo, activate them, and send <kbd>F5</kbd> to them.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I found this one but I wanted to get something native.